# Голосование на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, проектирование

Возможно глупый вопрос, но как принято обеспечивать уникальность голосования (т.е. чтобы один человек голосовал не более одного раза) на сайте **не требующем** авторизации? Пока приходит в голову только куки и/или запоминание IP-адреса голосовавшего. Может еще что-то есть?

Comment: Наверняка дело в IP. Попробуйте на такой сайт через прокси еще раз зайти.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin мне нужно не проголосовать, а написать свою систему голосования

Comment: Объединить IP и куки.

Comment: Вроде где-то обсуждалось... без авторизации ничто не гарантирует, что один человек не проголосует больше одного раза....IP могут быть разные, куки и все что хранится в браузере - затереть, заходить через прокси, TOR, VPS и прочее. эмулировать браузер, эмулировать ОС, делать запрос вообще неоткрывая этот несчастный браузер. Миллион и один способ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нашел мегастатью по идентификации через JS http://javascript.ru/unsorted/id в статье описан 100 и один способ идентифицировать пользователя. Остановлюсь на ней. К сожалению, здесь не приветствуется оставление ссылок в ответах, поэтому оставлю все в комментариях. Может кто оформит ответ

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не поможет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский абсолютного счастья никто не обещал :)