# Ограничить доступ к веб-странице с конкретного устройства?

Tags: php, сервер, ip, nat

Меня спрашивали, как сделать так, чтобы человек зайдя с конкретного компьютера на сайт и купив платный доступ на конкретную страницу, мог в дальнейшем только с этого компьютера на эту страницу и заходить?

В чем моя логика неверна?

1. самый надежный способ идентифицировать устройство (например, компьютер) в сети - mac-адрес, хотя и тот перепиливают умельцы
2. второй по надежности ip-адрес, который определяет уже не устройство, а "узел" в сети - вчера на ip висел конкретный комп, через полчаса утюг.
3. большинство сидит на динамических IP провайдера, а значит он переменен
4. на динамическом IP провайдера я не одинок и могут быть еще абоненты

Вывод:

Нельзя гарантированно идентифицировать конкретное устройство (того самого пользователя с тем самым пк) в сети и дать доступ к веб-странице исключительно ему?

И решение только такое - авторизации, верификации, доступы по уникальным ссылкам и тп. То есть работает, но технически зайти можно с любого устройства.

Answer (score 5):

Все Вы правильно понимаете. IP-адрес - это ни о чем, а до MAC адреса Вы не доберетесь

> платный доступ к веб-странице

Логично будет давать доступ не устройству, а человеку. Вот, допустим, я купил у Вас доступ. У меня дома два ноута и телефон. И еще комп на работе. Мне для каждого устройства покупать доступ?

Логично будет сделать доступ по логину/паролю. Или по номеру телефона с отправкой кода подтверждения по СМС. Если хотите, то при создании новой сессии, разрывайте предыдущую сессию для этого логина

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! (подправил вопрос). Да, логично, что надо давать доступ человеку. Но интересует именно гипотетическая возможность давать доступ устройству, а не человеку. На чем человек и настаивал и мол видел где-то)

Comment: Да, такое есть и для гмейла и для стима. Надо как-то идентифицировать компьютер. Присвоить ему какой-то ид. Например поставить куку comp_id=1736453784764623562525 . И где-то хранить информацию, что для данного ид есть доступ. Помимо кук есть и другие способы пометить компьютер.

Comment: Но кука и сессия не вечна. Закрыл браузер, почистил кеш и до свидания.

Comment: @Ilyasnake Я когда-то пытался решать подобную задачу. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660023/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5 Почитайте, может, что найдете. Если Вам нужна 100% гарантия, то забудьте про браузер - пишите своего клиента

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но дело то не в браузере, его отсутствие не дает 100% гарантии. Технология то остается та же)

Comment: @Ilyasnake Именно в браузере. При наличии своего клиента Вы можете передавать в протоколе любые данные из окружения - MAC-адрес, IMEI, версию прошивки.... И хранить данные можно в любом месте. А повреждение данных - это просто потеря ключа

Comment: Ок, понял, благодарю, полезная информация :)